# Laravel 8 - Variables in .env were initially read, suddenly they were all null

Tags: php, laravel-8

initially all variables in .env are read after doing this method.

php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear

but suddenly some time later all variables in .env read null.

all variables in .env should always be read apart from null because they have been set before